# how to use pointer to a pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

What are the uses of a pointer to a pointer in `C` and when to use?
Because I'm used to see something like this most often
     `const char *foo(char **foo);`
but when I do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *foo(char **foo)
{
printf("b : %s \n ", foo);
*foo = "World";
printf(" c %s \n ", foo);
}

main()
{
static char *test = "Hello";
foo(&test);
printf("a : %s \n ", test);
}
```

it compiles good but both b and c get corrupted and a never changes.
please help me , what am I doing wrong?

Comment: change to `printf("b : %s \n ", *foo);` ... `printf(" c %s \n ", *foo);` and `return *foo;`

Comment: If that "compiles good", then you are using the wrong compiler, the wrong settings or ignoring the warnings the compiler is giving you.  gcc gave me three warnings:

Comment: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char **' [-Wformat=]
      printf("b : %s\n", foo) ;
    warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char **' [-Wformat=]
      printf("c : %s\n", foo) ;
    warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]

Comment: Try compiling with -Wall option.

Comment: Thanks i did, thats my problem i guess.
I also understand that pointer to a pointer can be used to modify the pointer, so this is okay now!

 #include <stdio.h>
 char *foo(char **foo)
 {
 printf("b : %s \n ", *foo);
 *foo = "World";
 printf(" c %s \n ", *foo);
 return *foo;
 }

 int main()
 {
 static char *test = "Hello";
 foo(&test);
 printf("a : %s \n ", test);
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pointer to a pointer is a form of multiple indirection, or a chain of pointers. Normally, a pointer contains the address of a variable. When we define a pointer to a pointer, the first pointer contains the address of the second pointer, which points to the location that contains the actual value.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_to_pointer.htm